# Send keys not working selenium webdriver python showing error element not interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to send text to description text area
here is the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/') 
search_bar = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
search_bar.click()
search_bar.send_keys("Geeks for geeks ") 
searchbutton=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]')
searchbutton.click()
```

[error occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6aiW.png).